# Teamviewer 11 can't find network on ubuntu server

Tags: server, remote-desktop, teamviewer

So i've set up an ubuntu server that has tightvncserver installed. so i connect with a vnc client and I tried to install teamviewer so i could remotely manage the server(yes I know I could just port forward port 5901). but for some reason teamviewer is always telling me "Not ready, please check your connection". Even though the connection is obviously working as i've vnc'd into it. I tried doing a fresh install and rebooting the server, nothing works. Any suggestions?

Comment: port 5901 is of `tightvncserver`. As an alternative to port 80 HTTP, port 443 HTTPs is also being checked. In addition, it is also possible to open only port 5938 TCP on the outgoing side (required for mobile connections). So you should forward port 5938 and make sure HTTP and HTTPs done too.

Comment: Did you activate Incoming LAN connections by selecting accept or accept exclusively in Teamviewer setting?